# How to use range join between 2 dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

i have 2 dataframes productDates and dimDate. dimDate has range of dates for every year.
I wanted to generate range of dates falls between minDate and maxDate for every product.

[image]

Finally after joining 2 dataframes, output df will be..

[image]

Comment: productDate = productDate.alias("sk").join(dim_date.alias("d").hint("range_join",1000), col("d.Date") \
                                     .between(col("sk.minDate"), col("sk.maxDate"))) \
                                     .select("sk.*","d.DateKey") \
                                     .orderBy("Product","VersionDate","date")


Tried this way, but not getting exact date range as I am expected.

Comment: instead of an equality join you can try `df1.join(df2, [df1.col<=df2.col1, df1.col>=df2.col2], 'left')`

Comment: 1st comment gave me expected results if I use distinct() and orderBy appropriate date cols

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataframe "dimDate" and "productDates", represented as "a" and "b":

```
range_join = a.join(b, [a.id == b.id, b.date.between(a.min_date, a.max_date)])
```